# Curl Bad Request 400 on curl to docker server container

Tags: docker

I am trying to make calls to my application that is inside a docker container from the host machine.

Although port 7777 is exposed:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e447cb3d2db5        eosio/eos           "/bin/bash"              3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:7777->7777/tcp   server
```

When making the curl request, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

```
$ curl -vv -X POST http://127.0.0.1:7777/v1/chain/get_info
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 7777 (#0)
> POST /v1/chain/get_info HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:7777
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

the docker network is:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
d3d275c83226        bridge              bridge              local
9f6a5439c22c        eosnetwork          bridge              local
db156b84ea13        host                host                local
83e9116a4419        none                null                local
```

The host is a linux/ubuntu machine (I read there were similar issues, but only on windows). 
Any idea why it is happening and how to fix it?
Let me know if you need more info

## UPDATE

curl to the ip of the container works:

```
$ curl  -X POST http://172.18.0.2:7777/v1/chain/get_info
{"server_version":"08819aae","chain_id":"aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906","head_block_num":8085665,"last_irreversible_block_num":8085335,"last_irreversible_block_id":"007b5f5749c6dd4f268adc7e93597d0d6e0f8a6e2f04ec3f7b6c45e292ecac0f","head_block_id":"007b60a1e043ecee30589a74540ef241a287f16a0610b6d2fa33421adefe366a","head_block_time":"2018-07-27T19:08:14.500","head_block_producer":"eos42freedom","virtual_block_cpu_limit":200000000,"virtual_block_net_limit":1048576000,"block_cpu_limit":200000,"block_net_limit":1048576,"server_version_string":"v1.2.5"}
```

but I need it to work on from 127.0.0.1 (so I can expose it to external calls from the internet). Anyway to achieve that?

Comment: Is your docker-host machine running in a VM ? if YES then you can put it on bridged network.

Comment: Are you running new Docker for Windows or old docker machine?

Comment: I am on amazon ec2 instance ubuntu 16.04. I think that I need to run the container with --net=host. but is running a long process and I would prefer not to stop it to check.. is there a way to change network while it is still working?

Comment: I can confirm that running with --net=host solves the issue.